# Two-finger-scroll won't autorotate (18.10)

Tags: touchscreen, multi-touch, display-rotation

I have a Dell Precision 5530 2-in-1 and with Ubuntu 18.10 everything works *ridiculously* well.

There is one (admittedly rather minor) issue though.
When I go into tablet mode the two-finger-scroll won't adjust to the new orientation.
So to scroll up/down I need to scroll left/right. Everything else, as far as I can tell so far, works.

This goes for the touchscreen as well as the touchpad (when I manually rotate the screen via script so the keyboard/touchpad still works).

Does anyone know how to either fix this or where I can find the two-finger-scroll... settings?